# how to detect I touch on specific area?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, touch, uitouch

I have add one `UIView` ("Box") in my view and I want detect touch in it.

I searching in google and this site and find many answer but I want that when touch on Box View (only box View) show me in console `NSLog("1")` and when touch on my view **except** Box place (in other to out of Box View my console Show me `NSLog("2")`)

I'm so confused please help me. this is my code:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *Box;
@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize window,Box;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

    Box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53.0, 100.0, 214, 124)];
    [Box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:Box];

}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend you can use this code for detect view that you touched this :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view]== Box)
    {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"1");
}
```